# How do I read part of a Excel sheet, instead of the whole with Java?

Tags: java, mysql, excel, xssf

I made a small application which reads in an Excel File. I connected it to my MySQL Database so that I can put the file into the database, which contains multiple tables. However, when implementing the values into the 'Orders' table, there is an SQLException and the values do not get into the database. That's the exception in the CustomerMC class. The values of the 'Customers' table do get into the database.

The code I have contains a main where I read the file and make instances of Customer and Order, two container classes where the values get into, a connection class, which is not relevant for this, and a Model Class for the Customer where the query is located.

Main:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
    CustomerMC cmc = new CustomerMC();
    ArrayList<Customer> customers = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<Order> orders = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        try (FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("C:/Users/Wout/Desktop/ProjectTest.xlsx"))) {
            XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook(file);
            XSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheetAt(0);

            Iterator<Row> rowIterator = sh.iterator();
            while(rowIterator.hasNext()) {

                Row row = rowIterator.next();
                Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();

                int counter = 0;
                int cid = 0;
                int OrderID = 0;
                String name = "";
                String purchase = "";
                String age = "";
                String product = "";

                while (cellIterator.hasNext() && row.getRowNum() != 0) {
                    Cell cell = cellIterator.next();
                    counter++;

                    switch (counter) {
                        case 1:
                            cid = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 2:
                            name = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 3:
                            purchase = cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 4:
                            age = "" + cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 5:
                            OrderID = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 6:
                            product =  "" + cell.getStringCellValue();
                            break;
                        case 7:
                            cid = (int)cell.getNumericCellValue();
                            break;
                    }
                }
                if(row.getRowNum() != 0) {
                    Customer customer = new Customer(cid,name,purchase,age);
                    Order order = new Order(OrderID, product, cid);
                    customers.add(customer);
                    orders.add(order);
                }


            }
        }
    } catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("File has not been found");
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("IOException");
    }

    for(Order order : orders) {
        System.out.println(order.toString());
        cmc.insertOrder(""+order.getOrderid(), order.getProduct(), ""+order.getCid());
    }

    for(Customer customer : customers){
         System.out.println(customer.toString());
         cmc.insertCustomer(""+customer.getCid(), customer.getName(), customer.getPurchase(), customer.getAge());          
    }


}
```

Container Classes:

```
public class Customer {
private int cid;
private String name;
private String purchase;
private String age;

public Customer(int cid, String name, String purchase, String age) {
    this.cid = cid;
    this.name = name;
    this.purchase = purchase;
    this.age = age;
}

public int getCid() {
    return cid;
}

public void setCid(int cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public String getPurchase() {
    return purchase;
}

public void setPurchase(String purchase) {
    this.purchase = purchase;
}

public String getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(String age) {
    this.age = age;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + cid + " ; "+ name + " ; " + purchase + " ; " + age;
}

public class Order {
private int orderid;
private String product;
private int cid;

public Order(int orderid, String product, int cid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
    this.product = product;
    this.cid = cid;
}

public int getOrderid() {
    return orderid;
}

public void setOrderid(int orderid) {
    this.orderid = orderid;
}

public String getProduct() {
    return product;
}

public void setProduct(String product) {
    this.product = product;
}

public int getCid() {
    return cid;
}

public void setCid(int cid) {
    this.cid = cid;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "" + orderid + " ; " + product + " ; " + cid;
}
```

Customer Model Class:

```
public class CustomerMC {
private Connection connection;
private PreparedStatement pst;
String query;
ResultSet rs;

public CustomerMC(){
    try{
       connection = SimpleDataSourceV2.getConnection(); 
    }
    catch(SQLException e){
        System.out.println("Connection failure");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public String insertCustomer(String cid, String name, String purchase, String age) {
    String returning = null;
    try {
        query = "insert into CustomerService values(?,?,?,?);";

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(cid));
        pst.setString(2, name);
        pst.setString(3, purchase);
        pst.setString(4, age);

        int response = pst.executeUpdate();
        returning = response +" Records has/have been edited";

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        returning = "An error has occured";
        System.out.println(returning);

    }

    return returning;

}
public String insertOrder(String orderid, String product, String id) {
    String returning = null;
    try {
        query = "insert into CustomerService values(?,?,?,?);";

        pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
        pst.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(orderid));
        pst.setString(2, product);
        pst.setInt(3, Integer.parseInt(id));

        int response = pst.executeUpdate();
        returning = response +" Records has/have been edited";

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        returning = "xx";
        System.out.println(returning);

    }

    return returning;

}
```

Obviously there is one more class with the connection to the database. That's not relevant for this question so I decided to leave it out.

Then my Excel Sheet is a simple sheet, where cid, name, purchaser and age are the 'Customer' table and OrderID, Product and cid are the 'Orders' table. Cid in Orders is the Foreign Key to Customers. Excel automatically generates that field as the value it gets in the customers table. I re-implement the cid value to make it easier for myself.

Table: https://prnt.sc/ff1yd0

The output I am getting after running is as following:

```
    1 ; Monitor ; 1
    java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
    2 ; Couch ; 2
    3 ; Appartment ; 3
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2794)
        at 
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
        at 
     com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
        at 
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
        at 
    com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
        at p4project.CustomerMC.insertOrder(CustomerMC.java:66)
        at p4project.Main.main(Main.java:103)
    java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1
```

`at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1074)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)`

I don't know why the second table doesn't implement and I hope someone can help! Any help is appreciated.

Comment: You should post the exception you're seeing.

Comment: Update the question with the stack trace of the exception. You should print the stack trace instead of 'xx', which doesn't tell you anything about what is wrong

Comment: https://prnt.sc/ff25z7 ^ That's the output with the stacktrace. The line of errors you see repeat afterwards aswell. Couldn't get it all in one shot.

Comment: Don't use a link. Edit the question and add the stack trace.

Comment: There you go. Sorry, had some trouble getting it into a code format. The error repeats everytime it prints ID ; product ; CID

Answer (score 1):

Your exception is thrown at: `CustomerMC.insertOrder(CustomerMC.java:66)` and says
`java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count`.

Your CustomerService table seems to have 7 columns but your want to insert a row with only 4 values. This is not possible. You have to provide a value for each column (if you do not specifiy the names of the columns where you want to insert your values). You can also insert null values, if your schema allows it, but you have to specifiy it. The statement does not know which columns you want to leave blank.

Comment: I just noticed there was a mistake in my file.. I fixed that but I stumbled upon another error. Question wil be edited.

Comment: In general: If you have another question(that is not very close to your first one) write a new question. Otherwise my answer looses the context to the original question.